# C++ reading from file to std::wstring

Tags: c++, file, widestring

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::wfstream file("../Data/books.txt", std::wios::in);
    std::vector<std::wstring> lines;
    std::wstring line;

    while (!file.eof())
    {
        std::getline(file, line);
        lines.push_back(line);
    }

    for (const auto& item : lines)
        std::wcout << item << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Using that code, I am aiming to read all of the lines from a file and store them in a `std::vector`.

File has the following content:

```
Bir Ömür Nasıl Yaşanır
İlber Ortaylı
1
1
1
```

But when I print the elements of the vector, the only output shown is `Bir`.

The way for reading from file to `std::string` is basically this, is it different for `std::wstring`?  If so, how can I do it with `std::wstring`?

Comment: Unrelated: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: What character encoding is used by the file? Make sure it matches what C++ is using to read it.

Comment: First off, use `std::wifstream` instead of `std::wfstream`+`std::wios::in`. And second, you will likely have to [`imbue()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) an appropriate `locale` into the stream to handle the translation of the file's bytes into `wchar_t` characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)